# How to clear WooCommerce billing email and billing phone checkout fields after place order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How do I clear a specfic checkout fields in WooCommerce after placing an order?

For example `Billing email` and `Billing Phone`. So that when the registered customer makes his/her next order, he/she has to fill that fields again?

I see this code, but this clean all the fields, i need only a specific field. Any advice?

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string',10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `woocommerce_checkout_get_value` hook has 2 arguments:

- `$value` argument that is returned
- `$input` argument to target checkout field(s)

So in your case, you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_get_value( $value, $input ) {
    // Target checkout fields. Multiple fields can be added, separated by a comma
    if ( in_array( $input, array( 'billing_phone', 'billing_email' ) ) ) {
        $value = '';
    }

    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value' , 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_get_value' , 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this with some custom javascript:

```
document.getElementById('fieldID').value = ''
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('#fieldID').val('');
```